# Git cloning error

Tags: git, github

I am following steps described in [this page](http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/client_coding/building_the_standalone_client) to Build a Windows Zotero Standalone Client.
After running following command I get error message, as you see after command.
What is wrong?

```
$ git clone --recursive git://github.com/zotero/zotero-standalone-build.git
Cloning into 'zotero-standalone-build'...
remote: Counting objects: 942, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (565/565), done.
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer <-- means usually operating system level network disconnection. Maybe your firewall plays tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be a public key issue with github. try cloning with the url as 
`https://github.com/zotero/zotero-standalone-build.git`

instead. 
this requires no key based auth. I'm managing to clone this repo with both options BTW.